# Solr dataimporter.functions.formatDate get current date

Tags: lucene, solr

I´m using solr 3.2 version.
I need to get the current date in this format: yyyyMMdd and then use that result in a delta query

I´ve tried using this wiki http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#A_VariableResolver

```
${dataimporter.functions.formatDate('NOW', yyyyMMdd)}
```

But I get this exception:
Throwable occurred: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EvaluatorBag$4.evaluate(EvaluatorBag.java:146)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EvaluatorBag$5.get(EvaluatorBag.java:222)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EvaluatorBag$5.get(EvaluatorBag.java:209)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.VariableResolverImpl.resolve(VariableResolverImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TemplateString.fillTokens(TemplateString.java:81)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TemplateString.replaceTokens(TemplateString.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.VariableResolverImpl.replaceTokens(VariableResolverImpl.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.ContextImpl.replaceTokens(ContextImpl.java:256)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SqlEntityProcessor.nextModifiedRowKey(SqlEntityProcessor.java:84)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper.nextModifiedRowKey(EntityProcessorWrapper.java:262)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.collectDelta(DocBuilder.java:884)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doDelta(DocBuilder.java:284)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doDeltaImport(DataImporter.java:374)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:413)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:392)

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote both arguments.

```
${dataimporter.functions.formatDate('NOW', 'yyyyMMdd')}
```